# Broken flair images in closed Area51 beta user lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, broken-link

I found a minor bug that affects [closed beta proposals from Area51](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site:area51.stackexchange.com+didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta,+and+has+been+closed.+&pbx=1&oq=site:area51.stackexchange.com+didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta,+and+has+been+closed.+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=58l5462l0l5677l39l31l3l0l0l0l223l3241l15.12.2l29l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=6a9b72ab3639bcc3&biw=1521&bih=902). *

If you look at the [list of users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) for such a proposal, you'll see that the flair includes a broken image link:

[image]

The source for these is just an empty `img` tag, since obviously the beta's image was taken offline again:

```
<img src="">
```

So, probably a minor thing to fix by just removing the tag altogether.

<sub>* sorry, couldn't come up with an internal search as I'm not used to how Area51 works</sub>.

Comment: I think there's no internal way to search for text such as `didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed. `

Comment: @genesis Of course not, but maybe through status operators. Who knows, doesn't matter really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. (Yup, we just removed the `img` tags pointing to the favicons of closed sites.)